# min-width and max-width with the same value?

Tags: css, width

In the past, I saw the next css and I was thinking if there is some actual difference between

```
min-width: 90px;
max-width: 90px;
```

and

```
width: 90px;
```

Comment: Note that for heights - min/max heights don't get inherited by child elements - so there will be a difference between `height:90px` and `min-height:90px;max-height:90px` https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/MXJzqa

Comment: @VXp this generalization is simply wrong. see my comment under Temani's answer

Answer (score 22):

using `width` will simply specify fixed width over the element without paying attention to its content (so you can have overflow) :

```css
div {
  width: 80px;
  border:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/100/" />
</div>
```

Using `max-width` means that the element will have an **upper bound** for its width. So its width can be from 0 to max-width depending on its content.

```css
div {
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.diff {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <!-- this i a block element so max-width prevent it from taking 100% width -->
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/100/" />
</div>
<div class="diff">
  <!-- this i an inline-block element so max-width has no effect in this case cause the content is taking less than 300px  -->
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/100/" />
</div>
<div>
  <!-- You have overflow because the element cannot have more than 300 of width -->
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/100/" />
</div>
```

And `min-width` specify **lower bound** for width. So the width of the element will vary from min-width to ... (it will depend on other style).

```css
div {
  min-width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.diff {
  display: inline-block;
  min-height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/100/" />
</div>
<div class="diff">
  
</div>
<div class="diff">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/100/" />
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/100/" />
</div>
```

---

So if you specify `min-width` and `max-width`, you will set up a lower and upper bound and if both are equal it will be the same as simply specifing a `width`.

```css
div {
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.diff {
  display: inline-block;
  min-height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/100/" />
</div>
<div class="diff">
  
</div>
<div class="diff">
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/100/" />
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://lorempixel.com/400/100/" />
</div>
```

### **Special Cases**

In some particular cases, `width` will not give the same result as `min-width`/`max-width` like with Flexbox where we have the shrink feature that allow an element [to shrink to fit its container](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49492208/8620333)

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  margin:5px;
}
.box > div {
  border:2px solid;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div style="width:300px"></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div style="min-width:300px;max-width:300px;"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the second case the element will not shrink because, unlike `width`, `min-width` will prevent this.

Another case is the use of `resize` property:

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: both;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:300px"></div>

<div style="min-width:300px;max-width:300px;"></div>
```

As you can see, we can resize the element defined by `width` and not the one defined by `min-width`/`max-width`

---

We should also note that `min-width`/`max-width` is more powerful than `width`. Setting the 3 properties to different values will make `min-width` the winner

```css
.box {
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 50px;
  width:100px;
  min-width:200px;
  max-width:150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

This means that we can override a value set by `width` using `min-width`/`max-width` but not the opposite

Comment: You are not answering the question. The question is why you should use min-width and max-width with the same value instead of just the width attribute.

Comment: @fcortes am explaining both of them so at then end we can say that using both are the same. Am adding it to my answer

Comment: It should be added that for some elements, e.g. textareas (resizable by default) this makes a difference! setting `width` will set the initial width but the user will be able to  drag the corner of the element and make it smaller or bigger. Only specifying `min-width` and `max-width` will lock the size so that the user cannot resize beyond certain dimensions.

Comment: @tObi I think this should be the answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the situation in which you're using it you'll see the same behaviour from both or not - `tl;dr` the answer is yes, there's a difference between those.

#### width:90px

First of all, the theory behind is that `width:90px` will initially set the `width` of an element to be `90px` when browser loads the page. However, this could be modified by a user, optionally.

#### min-width:90px & max-width:90px

These properties define the `upper` (max) and `lower` (min) boundaries of the `width` of an element. These properties override `width`, but, `width` doesn't override these properties.

To show it practically, I'll change the dimensions from `90px` to `100%` as it is hard to visually explain the difference with such a small size.

I'll divide the explanation in 2 sections.

#### Elements are not designed to be resizable by user (only browser)

If elements are not designed to be resizable and the browser will do all the element resizing by itself, and the elements can be resized, then you'll see no difference between these two - see `codepen` snippets here [max-width&min-width](https://codepen.io/rgomezrx/pen/ExezwjE) and [onlyWidth](https://codepen.io/rgomezrx/pen/yLROMdM).

#### Elements are designed to be resizable by user

If elements are designed to be resizable by the user, here is **the difference** between these 2 really show up.

```css
width:100%;
```

When above is specified, browser will initialise the element to that `width` and then, user can still modify the width of the element with the resize option for that element.

```css
min-width:100%;
max-width:100%;
```

However, when above is specified, the browser will initialise the element to the corresponding width, in this case `100%` (in your original case, `90px`) and these will be now constraints all the time, which makes the width of the element not being able to be resized, even though it is. See `codepen` snippet [here](https://codepen.io/rgomezrx/pen/dygMWPw) showing the **2 of them at the same time** so that you can see the difference

Hope this helps! :)