# Flex-shrink and flex-grow doesn't work together?

Tags: css, flexbox

```css
 #box-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 500px;
  }
  
  #box-1 {
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    height: 200px;
    flex-grow:1;
    flex-shrink:2;

  }
  
  #box-2 {
    background-color: orangered;
    height: 200px;
    flex-grow:2;
    flex-shrink:4;
    flex-basis:200px;
```

```html
<div id="box-container">
  <div id="box-1"></div>
  <div id="box-2"></div>
</div>
```

Hello , could someone explain me why doesn't flex-shrink work in here? I kept trying to change values but it seems like nothing changes. I'm pretty sure there isn't any typo. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is a good guide to understand how [Flexbox works](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/even-more-about-how-flexbox-works-explained-in-big-colorful-animated-gifs-a5a74812b053)

Comment: flex-shrink work only when the space is exceeded

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492208/why-is-a-flex-child-limited-to-parent-size/49492522#49492522

Comment: What are you trying to do?