# Creating a CSS Fill Utility for Flex Items?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, component-design

I'm reviewing SUITCSS's design of a fill utility:

```
.u-sizeFill {
  flex: 1 1 0% !important; /* 1 */
  flex-basis: 0% !important; /* 2 */
}
```

This would be applied to flex that where we want them to fill up the remaining space.

Just want to see whether I'm interpreting this right.  The basis is 0%, so the item can have 0 width by default?  The flex grow and flex shrink are both 1 so, it will grow and shrink at the same rate.  Is this interpretation correct?

```css
.u-sizeFill {
  flex: 1 1 0% !important; /* 1 */
  flex-basis: 0% !important; /* 2 */
}
```

```html
<div style="display: flex; background-color: yellow; width: 5rem; height: 3rem">
      <div style="min-width: 0" class="u-sizeFill">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, probo option similique vix te, ei summo
        aliquip nec. Atqui diceret ceteros.
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 0% doesn't always mean width equal to 0 .. and you need to consider the min-width setting for the shrink effect

Comment: this will probably help you better understand : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34355447/8620333 / https://stackoverflow.com/a/36247448/8620333

Comment: OK - So even though the basis is 0%, the `min-width` and `min-height` are still `auto` so the flex item will not be smaller than the content it is holding?

Comment: yes exactly ...

Comment: Cool - Thanks for pointing that out - Good to know!

Comment: I tried playing around with adding `min-width: 0` in a demo, and it looks like the `u-sizeFill` overrides that ... in other words even though `min-width: 0` is set, we cannot size the flex item to anything smaller than the content it is holding ...

Comment: try to create a full demo so we can better see

Comment: Added one with `min-width` set.  The content still overflows the element boundaries.

Comment: I think you are miss understanding how shrink/grow should work. In your case there will be no shrink and no grow. You applied a fixed width to parent element and the child element will fit this width and the text will simply break in different lines. It's like you write text inside `p`. If there is a lot of text you will have multilines of text. Here is another question that might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/49492522/8620333 .. follow the MDN link to see the complete flex algorithm. (if not I will try to write a details answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two different situations in order to understand the use case of this class. Either this class is applied to all the elements or to only one element.

First we should notice that `flex-shrink:1` is the default value so we are only setting `flex-grow:1` and `flex-basis:0%`

### **When applied to all the elements**

In such situation this class will allow us to distribute **all the space** equally without considering the content of the different elements. It will not only distribute the **free space**.

Here is a basic example:

```css
.box {
  display:flex;
  border:1px solid;
  margin:5px;
}
.box > span {
  flex:1 1 0%;
  background:yellow;
  outline:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>text</span>
  <span>more text</span>
  <span>another long text here</span>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <span>A</span>
  <span>more text here</span>
  <span>another loooong text here</span>
</div>
```

Notice how in the below code our 3 elements have equal size even if the content will change. We created a 3 column layout.

Now, let's remove `flex-basis:0%` and keep only `flex-grow:1`

```css
.box {
  display:flex;
  border:1px solid;
  margin:5px;
}
.box > span {
  flex-grow:1;
  background:yellow;
  outline:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>text</span>
  <span>more text</span>
  <span>another long text here</span>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <span>A</span>
  <span>more text here</span>
  <span>another loooong text here</span>
</div>
```

We no more have equal elements and the width will change depending on the content because we are distrbuting the free space!

Here is from [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#flex-property) an illustration that will make you better understand:

[image]

> A diagram showing the difference between "absolute" flex (starting from a basis of zero) and "relative" flex (starting from a basis of the item’s content size). The three items have flex factors of 1, 1, and 2, respectively: notice that the item with a flex factor of 2 grows twice as fast as the others.

### **When applied to one the element**

In this case, we will ensure that this element will not affect the other elements when added to the layout as it will simply take the remaining space if any. In other words, its content will not get considering in the space distribution.

Here is an example:

```css
.box {
 margin:5px;
 border:1px solid;
 display:flex;
}
.box > span:not(.extra) {
  width:40%;
  background:yellow;
  outline:1px solid;
  min-height:30px;
}
.extra {
  flex:1 1 0%;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span class="extra">I am extra</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span class="extra">I am extra element with long text</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span class="extra">..</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

As you can see, in all the cases the extra element will simply take the `20%` remaining space without affecting the layout.

Now remove the `flex-basis` and you will see a different behavior:

```css
.box {
 margin:5px;
 border:1px solid;
 display:flex;
}
.box > span:not(.extra) {
  width:40%;
  background:yellow;
  outline:1px solid;
  min-height:30px;
}
.extra {
  flex-grow:1;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span class="extra">I am extra</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span class="extra">I am extra element with long text</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span class="extra">..</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

As you can see in the second situation, our elements will shrink breaking the initial layout which may not be an intended result.

Comment: Thank you!  That was a huge help!  YOU ROCK!!