# Combining flex shorthand with percentage width?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The SUITCSS size utilities combine flex shorthand with percentage width into `u-sizeXofY` utilities.

[Here's is a link to the tests](http://suitcss.github.io/utils-size/test/).

The `flex` property is set like this:

```
flex: 0 0 100%;
```

And it's combined with `u-sizeXofY` utilities like this:

```
 width: 50% !important;
```

What I'm trying to understand is why they are doing that?

What is the reason for combining `flex: 0 0 100%` with the `width: 50% !important;` utility?

Comment: By understanding the difference between _flex-basis_ and _width_, and how the other two short hand values (_flex-grow/flex-shrink_) impact the same, this post might even be a duplicate, at least a very good read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352140/what-are-the-differences-between-flex-basis-and-width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the class `u-sizeXofY` is defined as follow:

```
-webkit-flex-basis: auto !important;
-ms-flex-preferred-size: auto !important;
flex-basis: auto !important;
width: 50% !important;
```

So if we combine this with `.u-fullWidthFlex` (`flex:0 0 100%`) we will have this setting:

```
width:50%;
flex-basis:auto; /*default value*/
flex-shrink:0;
flex-grow:0; /*default value*/
```

So basically we are simply adding `flex-shrink:0` to disable the shrink effect which will have an effect in case there is an overflow with multiple items.

Here is a basic example:

```css
.box {
  display:flex;
  width:300px;
  border:2px solid red;
  margin:10px;
}

.box > span {
  height:20px;
  background:yellow;
  outline:1px solid;
  width:50%;
}
.shrink > span {
 flex-shrink:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>

<div class="box shrink">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

You can get more details here: [Why is a flex-child limited to parent size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49492208/8620333).

In case you will enable the wrap, we can say that it's useless to add `flex-shrink:0` since we will trigger the wrapping instead of shrinking:

```css
.box {
  display:flex;
  width:300px;
  border:2px solid red;
  margin:10px;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.box > span {
  height:20px;
  background:yellow;
  outline:1px solid;
  width:50%;
}
.shrink > span {
 flex-shrink:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>

<div class="box shrink">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

---

Using this class will make sure that the width of the element will be half the width of the container thus you won't get suprised by any shrink effect which is not something trivial. Having an overflow, will be more logical as you will somehow understand that you made a mistake by add more element than needed or by forgetting to enable the wrapping.

Another reason to combine such classes may also be related to media query where we can for example define the `u-sizeXofY` at only some breakpoints thus you may have different behavior with and withount `flex-basis:0 0 100%`

```css
.box {
  display:flex;
  width:300px;
  border:2px solid red;
  margin:10px;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.box > span {
  height:20px;
  background:yellow;
  outline:1px solid;
  flex:0 0 100%;
}

@media all and (min-width:800px) {
  .half {
    width:50%!important;
    flex-basis:auto!important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span class="half"></span>
  <span class="half"></span>
  <span class="half"></span>
  <span class="half"></span>
</div>
```

As you can see, `flex:0 0 100%` will set an initial width for our element to be `100%` which is the default behavior of block element like `div` thus intuive for us. Then the `half` class will override this. If you remove `flex:0 0 100%` you will simply see nothing because the elements are empty.

Comment: Genius!  Thanks again!