# Why flex-shrink behaves this way in my example?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Could you give me an explanation of what is going here? (If it's possible attach links to the CSS spec)

When I set **flex-shrink** to **0** on **#grid-container** (`flex: 1 0 auto`), there appears a scroll bar for the whole page

But when I set **flex-shrink** to **1** on **#grid-container** (`flex: 1 1 auto`), the bar scroll bar appears only for  the #grid-container

In the code snippet below **flex-shrink** on **#grid-container** is set to to **0** (`flex: 1 0 auto`). Change it to **1**(`flex: 1 1 auto`) to see the difference

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  background-color: brown;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}

#grid-container {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: grid;
  overflow: hidden;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr; 
}

#grid-item {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  overflow: auto;
}

#list {
  overflow: auto;
}

#list-item {
  font-size: 140px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="grid-container">
    <div id="grid-item">
      <div id="list">
        <div id="list-item">1</div>
        <div id="list-item">2</div>
        <div id="list-item">3</div>
        <div id="list-item">4</div>
        <div id="list-item">5</div>
        <div id="list-item">6</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `flex` goes on the child elements, not on the flex container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting `flex-shrink:1` (the default value) you allow your element to shrink inside its flex container and since you set the `body` (the flex container) to be `height:100%` it will shrink to fit inside it creating the scroll bar only on the container because **its content** is overflowing. Te be more accurate the scroll bar is on `#grid-item` and not the container which is logical since this one is having `overflow:auto`.

Add border to better see this:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background:#fff;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background:red;
}

#header {
  background-color: brown;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}

#grid-container {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: grid;
  overflow: hidden;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr; 
  border:5px solid green;
}

#grid-item {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  overflow: auto;  
  border:5px solid blue;
}

#list {
 /* overflow: auto;  not needed*/
  border:5px solid yellow;
}

#list-item {
  font-size: 140px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="grid-container">
    <div id="grid-item">
      <div id="list">
        <div id="list-item">1</div>
        <div id="list-item">2</div>
        <div id="list-item">3</div>
        <div id="list-item">4</div>
        <div id="list-item">5</div>
        <div id="list-item">6</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also set `overflow:auto` to the container and you will have the scroll on the container and almost the same result

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background:#fff;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background:red;
}

#header {
  background-color: brown;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}

#grid-container {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: grid;
  overflow: auto;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr; 
  border:5px solid green;
}

#grid-item {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2; 
  border:5px solid blue;
}

#list {
 /* overflow: auto;  not needed*/
  border:5px solid yellow;
}

#list-item {
  font-size: 140px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="grid-container">
    <div id="grid-item">
      <div id="list">
        <div id="list-item">1</div>
        <div id="list-item">2</div>
        <div id="list-item">3</div>
        <div id="list-item">4</div>
        <div id="list-item">5</div>
        <div id="list-item">6</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

By disabling the shrink, **the element and its content** will overflow outside the body and also the html which will create a scroll bar on the viewport to be able to see the overflowing content. Adding `overflow:auto` is useless in this case since the parent height is the same as the content height.

Add background to body/html elements to better see the overflow when disabling the shrink

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background:#fff; /*to stop the propagation of the red color*/
  border:5px dotted purple;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background:red;
}

#header {
  background-color: brown;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}

#grid-container {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  overflow: hidden;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr; 
  border:5px solid green;
}

#grid-item {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  overflow: auto;  
  border:5px solid blue;
}

#list {
 /* overflow: auto;  not needed*/
}

#list-item {
  font-size: 140px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="grid-container">
    <div id="grid-item">
      <div id="list">
        <div id="list-item">1</div>
        <div id="list-item">2</div>
        <div id="list-item">3</div>
        <div id="list-item">4</div>
        <div id="list-item">5</div>
        <div id="list-item">6</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Related: [Why is a flex-child limited to parent size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49492208/8620333)

---

As a side note, if you remove `overflow:hidden` from the container the result will be the same for both cases:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background:#fff;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background:red;
}

#header {
  background-color: brown;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
}

#grid-container {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr; 
  border:5px solid green;
}

#grid-item {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  overflow: auto;   /*will do nothing*/
  border:5px solid blue;
}

#list {
 /* overflow: auto;  not needed*/
  border:5px solid yellow;
}

#list-item {
  font-size: 140px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header"></div>
  <div id="grid-container">
    <div id="grid-item">
      <div id="list">
        <div id="list-item">1</div>
        <div id="list-item">2</div>
        <div id="list-item">3</div>
        <div id="list-item">4</div>
        <div id="list-item">5</div>
        <div id="list-item">6</div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is due to [The Automatic Minimum Size of Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36247448/8620333) that will prevent the shrink effect.

Comment: Awesome answer, it saved me a lot of time. Also I figured out, that that
[Automatic Minimum Size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36247448/8620333) is applied to Grid items as well