# Truncate text in flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox, ellipsis

I have a header with a left and right side. The left side contains some text which I want to keep on a single line, truncating with ellipsis if needed. However, when I apply `white-space: nowrap` to it then the whole header goes outside its container. Here's what I mean:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.header {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.header-right,
.header-left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.title {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

img {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-left">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/181/181548.png">
      <span class="title">Title: Keep me on a single line</span>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/181/181548.png">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/181/181548.png">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/181/181548.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to keep the title on a single line but truncate it so the header doesn't go outside the bounds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to disable the default minimun width by adding `min-width:0` and disable the shriking for the images and their container by adding `flex-shrink:0;` and add `overflow:hidden`

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.header {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.header-right,
.header-left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  min-width:0; /* Added */
}

.title {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden; /* Added */
}

img {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  flex-shrink:0; /* Added */
}

.header-right {
  flex-shrink:0; /* Added */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header-left">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/181/181548.png">
      <span class="title">Title: Keep me on a single line</span>
    </div>
    <div class="header-right">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/181/181548.png">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/181/181548.png">
      <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/181/181548.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Related:**

[Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/8620333) (To understand the `min-width`)

[Why is a flex-child limited to parent size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49492208/8620333) (To understand the `flex-shrink`)