# Stop animation from right to left

Tags: html, css

I want this progress bar to animate only from left to right, starting from text. After animation ends from right to left, it starts animating from right to left, from some point. Note, I need to use the flexbox and width for text.

```css
.table-bars .bar-box .text {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0 30px 0 200px;
 width: 200px;
    text-align:right;
}
.bar-box {
    margin-bottom:20px;
   }
.table-bars div .progress {
    background-color: #0071b9;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-right: 13px solid rgb(0, 173, 239);
    -webkit-animation: progressBar 2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:both;
    -moz-animation: progressBar 2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode:both;
    height: 20px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes progressBar {
  0% { width: 0; }
  100% { width: 100%; }
}

@-moz-keyframes progressBar {
  0% { width: 0; }
  100% { width: 100%; }
}

.bar-box {
 display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-bars">
     <div class="bar-box">
           <div class="text"><span>TEXT</span></div>
           <div class="progress"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="bar-box">
           <div class="text"><span>Another TEXT</span></div>
           <div class="progress"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove the width from text

Comment: I need the width, because I have multiple texts that I need to style it aligned right

Comment: then add flex-shrink:0 to the text

Comment: That worked. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either add `flex-shrink:0` to avoid the shriking of the text because you are setting `width:100%`

```css
.table-bars .bar-box .text {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 30px 0 200px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: right;
  flex-shrink:0;
}

.bar-box {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.table-bars div .progress {
  background-color: #0071b9;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-right: 13px solid rgb(0, 173, 239);
  animation: progressBar 2s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  height: 20px;
}

@keyframes progressBar {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.bar-box {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-bars">
  <div class="bar-box">
    <div class="text"><span>TEXT</span></div>
    <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar-box">
    <div class="text"><span>Another TEXT</span></div>
    <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or animate the `flex-grow` instead of `width`:

```css
.table-bars .bar-box .text {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 30px 0 200px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: right;
  flex-shrink:0;
}

.bar-box {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.table-bars div .progress {
  background-color: #0071b9;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-right: 13px solid rgb(0, 173, 239);
  animation: progressBar 2s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  height: 20px;
}

@keyframes progressBar {
  0% {
    flex-grow: 0;
  }
  100% {
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}

.bar-box {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-bars">
  <div class="bar-box">
    <div class="text"><span>TEXT</span></div>
    <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="bar-box">
    <div class="text"><span>Another TEXT</span></div>
    <div class="progress"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Related: [Why is a flex item limited to parent size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49492208/8620333)