# Make div height the max-height of container div

Tags: html, css

I have a container `<div>` which has a `max-height` property. This `<div>` contains another `<div>`, and I want the child `<div>` to grow to the maximum height of its container.

```
<div id='parent'>
  <div id='child'>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is easy enough when the parent `<div>` has a *fixed* height, but I cannot find a solution for making the child `<div>` assume the *max-height* of the container. There is no padding or margin or anything to worry about - I simply need the child `<div>` to assume the `max-height` of the parent.

How can I do this?

Comment: just to clear your explanation do you mean to say if your parent height is 154px then you child height should be 154px too ?

Comment: Not quite - I mean to say if the parent max-height is 154 px, then the child height should be 154 px too.

Comment: I have posted the answer, feel free for any suggestion

Comment: Just setting child's height to 100% should be enough to make it use parent's height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the parent's display property to `flex`, and the flex direction to column:

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red; /** example - to show the effect on the parent **/
}

#child {
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to work simply because the child div has a greater height than max-height, but flex container somehow clips the height without overflow. Odd behaviour, but thank you.

Comment: @Owen not odd but logical: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49492522/8620333

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to note, 
1. Height should be in `vh` to achieve responsiveness, better when dealing with height CSS 
 2. it's preferable to use `vh` as the unit for height.

```css
.parent {
  max-height: 25vh;
  width: 15vw;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.child {
  background-color: brown;
  height: 25vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id='parent' class='parent'>
  <div id='child' class='child'>
  </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you - but I don't know the max-height of the parent container in advance, so it's not quite as simple as synchronising the value of the child's height to the max-height of the container.

Answer (score 0):

That is super simple to fix, simply add a height to your parent div.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

```
.parent{
  max-height:100px;
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  background:coral;
}
.child{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:blue;
}
```