# How to calculate the actual width of child elements of a flexbox container?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, flexbox, frontend

I have such html and css code. I have two questions:

1. When the window width is 600px, in theory, the left box should be of 150px width, because it's the 25% of the parent(600px), but the width is 120px.
2. The right box can not reach 100vw. It just takes the `widthOfParent` - `widthOfLeft`. I suppose it should somehow overflow and reach 100vw.

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div class="right"></div>
 </div>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  height: 300px;
  /* your code here */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
}

.left {
  background-color: #f44336;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.right {
  background-color: #2973af;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

codesanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-darkness-cu99x?file=/src/styles.css:0-293

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing the shrink effect. In all the cases the total width `100vw + 25%` is bigger than `100%` so both items will shrink equally.

Since your container is also full width, the overflow will always be equal to `25%` or `25vw`. Both element have the default shrink value `1` so we have a sum equal to `125vw`.

The first element width will be equal to: `25vw - (25vw * 25vw/125vw) = 20vw`
and the width of the second item will be: `100vw - (25vw * 100vw/125vw) = 80vw`

You can logically see that the total is `100vw` (`20vw + 80vw`) and when the screen width is equal to `600px`, `20vw` is equal `120px`.

To avoid this, disable the shrink effect on the first item by setting `flex-shrink:0`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 300px; /* your code here */
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  background-color: #f44336;
  width: 25%;
  min-width: 100px;
  flex-shrink:0;
}

.right {
  background-color: #2973af;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Related: [Why is a flex item limited to parent size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49492208/8620333)

Answer (score 0):

1. use "flex" property instead of width for the flex items

> ```
> .container {
>     height: 300px;
>     width: 600px; /* added fixed width for testing */
>     display: flex;
>     justify-content: start;
> }
>
> .left {
>     background-color: #f44336;
>     min-width: 100px;
>     flex: 1; /* 1/4 ratio within the parent element, as the other flex item in the parent is "flex: 3;" */
> }
>
> .right {
>     background-color: #2973af;
>     flex: 3; /* 3/4 ratio within the parent element, as the other flex item in the parent is "flex: 1;" */
> }
> ```

2. The right element cannot take 100% of the width, as it is together with the left div inside the flex parent and we assigned the width parameter as "flex: value" for both

CSS flex Property
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Comment: Hi @Rpx, Thank you for answering. Now I know I should use `flex` rather than `width` in flexbox. But I still don't understand that why the right box can't reach the width I explicitly assigned.