# width: 100% with display: flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm adding a toolbar to an application with multiple levels of flex elements.

```
 <div class="toolbar">
   <div class="button">Button1</div>
   <div class="button">Button2</div>
   <div class="button">Button3</div>
   ...
 </div>
```

It's gonna take up the whole width of the parent and use horizontal scrolling on overflow.

```
.toolbar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This works swimmingly in an empty document. However, because the application itself uses `display: flex`, toolbar's `width: 100%` becomes the width of the whole document, not the width of its immediate parent. `width: 100%` affects the outside flex layout! But having a fixed width, e.g. `width: 300px` works perfectly fine.

A demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6s23o7Lf/

Basically, I'm trying to get this:
[image]

But get this instead:
[image]

Is there a way to say that a flex item should take up all of the parent's width (all of its space along the secondary axis) without affecting its layout? Like `align-items: stretch`, but also cut off contents on overflow.

I tried making `toolbar` not a flex element (using `display: block` on it and `display: inline-block` on the buttons, with `white-space: nowrap` and all that jazz), but the width still comes from up the DOM tree.

For context, my end goal is similar to what you see at the bottom of an Excel document (left/right arrows are used for scrolling there):

[image]

---

[Edit] Note that this is quite different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492208/why-is-a-flex-item-limited-to-parent-size), because it involves nested flex elements with don't have fixed sizes.

Comment: flex-shrink: 0 ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif The answer you linked is interesting but quite different. It relies on flex container being at the top level and having fixed width, not being nested inside other flex divs of flexible sizes. Specifically, adding `flex-shrink: 0` to `.toolbar` has no effect unless I also do something like `width: 200px` on its parent.

Comment: Thanks for the information though, it's quite interesting

Comment: added another duplicate based on the answer you accepted

Comment: thanks, the new one discusses nested flex elements, which is spot on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a quick fix for this. Add `min-width: 50%;` to `.section`:

```css
.section {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 50%;
}
```

This will prevent either section from shrinking to less than half the width but allow them to grow to fill the full width.

NOTE: This is a simple fix that may not work if there are more sections!

UPDATE:

For more columns don't use the min-width property as shown above.

You should instead add `overflow: hidden;` to `.section` to prevent their children from forcing the width to increase.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! As you say, this is tricky to make work in a more complex application, unfortunately...

Comment: @NikitaRybak Added an update that will take care of more `.sections`.

Comment: Wow, `overflow: hidden` did it... I'd love to understand flexbox logic in this case, but it does solve the example in the question!

Comment: I had to use other workarounds in my actual application (`overflow: hidden` did not do it, unfortunately) and ended up 'fixing' the issue with `width: 100%` on some of the parent classes. `width: 100vw` also worked quite well. Mentioning in case somebody else is looking for a solution.

Comment: A similar-but-different solution with `min-width: 0` https://css-tricks.com/flexbox-truncated-text/

Answer (score 0):

edited from previous version
this version only use grid. Grid is really to structure the page, or an element in a page. Flex is ok to align element inside 1.

Here you have a grid with the external structure of 2 sections.
second section is a grid (nested grid). And tool bar is a nested of the nested.

```css
.everything {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.section {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.section:nth-child(2) {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.toolbar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(14, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
  overflow: scroll;
  align-self: end;
}

.toolbar .button {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toolbar .button:hover {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="everything">
  <div class="section">
    <div class="title">
      Section A
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="section">
    <div class="title">
      Section B
    </div>
    <div class="toolbar">
      <div class="button">Button1</div>
      <div class="button">Button2</div>
      <div class="button">Button3</div>
      <div class="button">Button4</div>
      <div class="button">Button5</div>
      <div class="button">Button6</div>
      <div class="button">Button7</div>
      <div class="button">Button8</div>
      <div class="button">Button9</div>
      <div class="button">Button10</div>
      <div class="button">Button11</div>
      <div class="button">Button12</div>
      <div class="button">Button13</div>
      <div class="button">Button14</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Pier. When I run this snippet, "Section B" still takes all the width while "Section A" is squeezed into a tiny space. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: And overall, do you mean that nested `display: flex` elements are not supported?

Answer (score 0):

the css of section has "width: 100%", your sectionA and section B all have the section class. The sectionA's parent is div of class everything, the sectionB's parent also is div of class everything. It is same to "width: auto".

If you want get right, you can replace the css section class of this:

```
.section {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

Comment: Thanks stul. When I use this code, I still see "Section B" take nearly whole width while "Section A" is squeezed into a tiny space. Does it look different to you?

Comment: @NikitaRybak the code of before is a error. I have updated the code, and you can try again。

Comment: I see, thanks! Unfortunately, there are more elements in the application (such as a sidebar, as well as borders/margins/padding), so I cannot specify exact width of the container...

Comment: you can fix the width of the sectionA, and do not set "section" class to sectionB' container . And the section B will fill whole left width