# how to do image scaling with window size

Tags: css, image

Seems so simple, but ...

scale image size with window size?

```
1)create a container for the image = entire window width, so container grows with window width
2)slap image inside the container
3)scale image based on % of the width of the container
```

HTML

```
<div class="imgEnclosure">
<img class="validatedImage"
     src="1776_Support/images/check_mark.png" alt="thisImage"
     onclick="SwapImages(this); return false" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.imgEnclosure {
    width: 100%;
}

.validatedImage {
    /* original size (w,h) = 220px by 108px */
    
    /*
        1.0em = font-size: 24px from html Selector
        so ... original size = 9.167em by 4.500em
    */
    
    max-width: 30%;
    min-width: 10%;
    
    height: auto;
}
```

The image shows the same size no matter how I change the browser window width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good Grief ...

Instead of:

```
max-width: 30%;
min-width: 10%;
```

Use

```
width: 30%;
```

Honestly, I could not ask for a simpler answer ... even though I do not understand why the `max-, min-width` response does not work?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure as to why it didn't work , I believe it could be an error in styling in the parent element or forced styling from parent elements that transferred to the child element .

Did you try placing the

`max-width: 30%; min-width: 10%;`

in your .imgEnclosure and not the img class itself? Maybe that would have worked too. I normally place positional styles in parent elements so that child elements would easily inherit the styling properties.

Regardless: do check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47133888/min-width-and-max-width-with-the-same-value) as it might answer your question! hope this helped :)

Comment: the answers containing questions are hard to process and adapt. please, verify if you can provide a working example by modifying the code excerpts from the question or providing your own.